# Should comparators be instantiated every time or just once?

Tags: java, comparator

With a custom comparator, are there any advantages to instantiating it every time instead of creating it as a constant (using anonymous class) and using that single instance?
I've always thought that there's no advantage to creating a new instance every time and had always gone the way of option #2 (single instance in static final field).

```
public class SomeClass {

  //First option:
  private static class SomeCustomComparator implements Comparator<SomeObject> {
    public int compare(SomeObject o1, SomeObject o2) {
      /*implementation*/
    }
  }

  //Second option:
  private static final Comparator<SomeObject> CUSTOM_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<SomeObject> {
    public int compare(SomeObject o1, SomeObject o2) {
      /*implementation*/
    }
  };

  public void doSomething() {
    //are there any advantages to one over the other?
    SortedSet<SomeObject> s1 = new TreeSet<>(CUSTOM_COMPARATOR);

    SortedSet<SomeObject> s2 = new TreeSet<>(new SomeCustomComparator());
  }
}
```

The assumption here is that no state needs to be kept in the comparator.

What if doSomething() gets called a lot? What if doSomething() gets called from multiple threads? What if CUSTOM_COMPARATOR were to be pulled out into a common class and made public instead of private?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the comparator has no state (and most won't) then it's absolutely fine to create a single instance and use that everywhere. Don't create extra objects just for the sake of it.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity--what type of comparator would have state?

Comment: Well, you might have a method that creates a `Comparator` based on its (immutable) input.  That wouldn't exactly be state, per se, but you'd need to construct different comparators for different input.

Comment: @climbage: I guess *in theory* you could have one which could have different modes, and you could change the mode when you wanted. But it would be very odd :)

Comment: @climbage I can imagine a comparator that changes behavior after seeing a special element. Never implemented one like that, though :)

Comment: Ah right, different modes.  I was envisioning the state changing during each comparison which would be... unfortunate.

Comment: Eh, a mutable comparator in the first place seems like a really bad idea.